# Get-ChildItem script hangs due to large object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Okay - I am brand new to PowerShell. I only started using it two weeks ago. I've scoured the web to create some scripts and now I'm trying something that seems a bit advanced and I'm uncertain how I should solve this.

I'm creating an audit script to determine what files are different between two backup repositories to ensure they've been properly synchronized (the synchronization scripts use robocopy and they've failed more than once without producing an error). The folders are quite extensive and upon occasion, I'm finding that the script just hangs on certain folders (always on the largest of them) and it will never complete due to this.

At first, I was using Get-ChildItem on the full source path, but that created a memory problem and the script would never complete. So, I thought I'd enumerate the child directories and perform a compare on each child directory... but depending on the folder, that goes bad as well.

Here is the script (using Powershell 2):

```
$serverArray=@("Server1","Server2","Server3")

for ($i=0; $i -lt 8; $i++) {

    $server = $serverArray[$i]
    $source="\\$server\Share\"

    $destination = "D:\BackupRepository\$server"
    # Copy to removable drive
    $remoteDestination = "T:\BackupRepository\" + $server

    $log = $server + "ShareBackup.log"
    $remoteLog = "Remote_" + $server + "ShareBackup.log"
    $logDestination = $localLogPath + $log
    $logUNCDestination = $uncLogPath + $log
    $logRemoteDestination = $localLogPath + $remoteLog
    $logUNCRemoteDestination = $uncLogPath + $remoteLog

    ## This file is used for the process of checking
    ## whether or not the backup was successful
    $backupReport = $localReportPath + $server + "ShareBackupReport.txt"
    $remoteBackupReport = $localReportPath + "Remote_" + $server + "ShareBackupReport.txt"

    ## Variables for the failure emails
    $failEmailSubject = "AUDIT REPORT for " + $server
    $failRemoteEmailSubject = "AUDIT REPORT for " + $server
    $failEmailBody = "The Audit for " + $server + " has found a file mismatch. Please consult the attached Backup Report."
    $failRemoteEmailBody = "The Audit of the Remote Backups for " + $server + " has found a file mismatch. Please consult the attached Backup Report."

    $sourceFolderArray = Get-ChildItem $source | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
    $sourceFolderCount = $sourceFolderArray.Count
    $mismatchCount = 0
    $remoteMismatchCount = 0

    for ($s1=0; $s1 -lt $sourceFolderCount; $s1++) {

        $sourceFolder = $sourceFolderArray[$s1].FullName
        $sourceFolderName = $sourceFolderArray[$s1].Name
        $destFolder = $destination + "\" + $sourceFolderName
        $remoteDestFolder = $remoteDestination + "\" + $sourceFolderName

        Write-Host "Currently working on: " $sourceFolderName

        $shot1 = Get-ChildItem -recurse -path $sourceFolder
        $shot2 = Get-ChildItem -recurse -path $destFolder
        $shot3 = Get-ChildItem -recurse -path $remoteDestFolder

        $auditReportDest = "C:\BackupReports\Audits\"
        $auditReportOutput = $auditReportDest + $server + "_" + $sourceFolderName + ".txt"
        $auditReportRemoteOutput = $auditReportDest + $server + "_Remote_" + $sourceFolderName + ".txt"
        $auditMismatchReport = $auditReportDest + "MismatchReport_" + $numericDate + ".txt"

        Compare-Object $shot1 $shot2 -PassThru > $auditReportOutput
        Compare-Object $shot2 $shot3 -PassTHru > $auditReportRemoteOutput

        $auditCompare = Get-ChildItem $auditReportOutput
        $auditRemoteCompare = Get-ChildItem $auditReportRemoteOutput

        if ($auditCompare.Length -gt 0) {
            $content = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $auditReportOutput
            Add-Content $auditMismatchReport $content
            Write-Host "Mismatch FOUND: " $sourceFolderName
            $mismatchCount = $mismatchCount + 1
            }
        if ($auditRemoteCompare.Length -gt 0) {
            $remoteContent = Get-ChilItem -Recurse $auditReportRemoteOutput
            Add-Content $auditMismatchReport $remoteContent
            Write-Host "Remote Mismatch FOUND: " $sourceFolderName
            $remoteMismatchCount = $remoteMismatchCount + 1
            }

        }

    send-mailmessage -from $emailFrom -to $emailTo -subject "AUDIT REPORT: Backups" -body "The full mismatch report is attached. There were $mismatchCount mismatched folders found and $remoteMismatchCount remote mismatched folders found. Please review to ensure backups are current." -Attachments "$auditMismatchReport" -priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer $emailServer

    }
```

What I've discovered when run interactively is that I'll get a "Currently working on FolderName" and if that object is "too large" (whatever that is), the script will just sit there at that point giving no indication of any error, but it will not continue (I've waited hours). Sometimes I can hit Ctrl-C interactively and rather than quitting the script, it takes the interrupt as a cancel for the current process and moves to the next item.

The rub is, I need to schedule this to happen daily to ensure the backups remain synchronized. Any help or insight is appreciated. And, yes, this is probably raw and inelegant, but right now I'm just trying to solve how I can get around the script hanging on me.

Comment: Are you just checking filenames, or are you also checking for length match?

Comment: Just checking filenames to ensure they exist. Enough files change from day to day that this is all that would be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what version of PS you're using, but Get-Childitem has known problems scaling to large directories:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow.aspx

If you're just comparing file names, you can get much better results in large directory structures using the legacy dir command.  The /b (bare) switch returns just the fullname strings that can be readily used with Powershell's comparison operators.

```
$sourcedir = 'c:\testfiles'
$source_regex = [regex]::escape($sourcedir)

(cmd /c dir $Sourcedir /b /s) -replace "$source_regex\\(.+)$",'$1'
```

This uses a regular expression and the -replace operator to trim the soruce directory off of the fullnames returned by dir.  The -replace operator will work with arrays, so you can do all of them in one operation without a foreach loop.

Comment: Using Powershell 2.0 - sorry. I should have posted that... it was in the tag, but that's nearly invisible. My bad. I'll check out dir... I didn't realize I could use that in a recursive scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the tag.  I believe the gci performance issue in that article does apply to V2.

Comment: First off - thanks for taking the time to help. I appreciate it. So, that's definitely progress, the problem is that since I'm comparing two completely different directory structures, the /b switch gives me complete paths... so Compare-Object always produces a full list (since nothing matches due to the full path). Is there something I can do in Compare-Object to have it ignore the base path or is there a way to have the dir command output everything OTHER than the base path?

Comment: You can, but it's quicker to just use the /b switch and then deal with the result using string operations.  I'll update the script with an example.

Comment: Many thanks sir! That did it for me. The large directories have proved to be no issue now. Marked as answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet to vote it up.

Comment: Glad to help!  Come back and see us again.

Comment: Anyone know whether Get-ChildItem still has problems with deep folder structures? I'm running it on a file server to get a complete directory and file listing (using Export-CSV). Leave it running and come back to find Powershell windows has closed