# Get-ChildItem on Multiple Computers, Performance Issues

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm wanting to improve on my script to be able to accomplish the following:

- Scan servers based on get-adcomputer on specific OUs.
- Scan each server based on whatever drive letter it has.
- Scan each server for *log4j*.
- Export all results to a CSV that identifies the folder path, name of file, and the server that the file was found on.

I have been using the following code to start with:

```
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=..." | Select -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($server in $Servers){
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {
       
    $Drives = (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Root

        foreach ($drive in $Drives){
    
        Get-ChildItem -Path $drive -Force -Filter *log4j* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | '
    
            foreach{
                $Item = $_
                $Type = $_.Extension
                $Path = $_.FullName
                $Folder = $_.PSIsContainer
                $Age = $_.CreationTime

                $Path | Select-Object `
                @{n="Name";e={$Item}}, `
                @{n="Created";e={$Age}},`
                @{n="FilePath";e={$Path}},`
                @{n="Extension";e={if($Folder){"Folder"}else{$Type}}}`
             } | Export-Csv C:\Results.csv -NoType
        }
   }
```

I am having the following issues and would like to address them to learn.

1. How would I be able to get the CSV to appear the way I want, but have it collect the information and store it on my machine instead of having it on each local server?
2. I have noticed extreme performance issues on the remote hosts when running this. WinRM takes 100% of the processor while it is running. I have tried -Include first, then -Filter, but to no avail. How can this be improved so that at worst, it's solely my workstation that's eating the performance hit?
3. What exactly do the ` marks do?

Comment: You're enumerating the entire FileSystem on your remote hosts, it is expected this will consume a good amount of memory and CPU. The code could be optimized a good amount but the resource issue on your hosts will persist.

Comment: [1] define your scriptblock OUTSIDE the `Invoke-Command`. it's easier to keep track of and _minutely _ faster. ///// [2] DO NOT use `ForEach-Object` to call `I-C` ... instead, feed the list of systems to the `I-C` call via the `-ComputerName` parameter. that will let things run in parallel. ///// [3] back ticks are for line wrapping - and are NOT needed when you have a natural line break like a pipe or a comma. lookee ... >>> Get-PowerShellBlog: Bye Bye Backtick: Natural Line Continuations in PowerShell — https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html <<<

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SantiagoSquarzon - that's going to be a performance hit.

Consider using writing a function to run `Get-ChildItem` recursively with the `-MaxDepth` parameter, including a `Start-Sleep` command to pause occasionally.  Also, you may want to note [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20010637/2554363)

You'd also want to Export-CSV to a shared network drive to collect all the machines' results.

The backticks indicate a continuation of the line, like `\` in bash.

Finally, consider using a Scheduled Task or start a powershell sub-process with a lowered process priority, maybe that will help?